# Set the hours part of a timestamp to a fixed value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a `TIMESTAMP` column named `request_date`.

I want to select the value of this column, but with the following condition: if the time is after 19:00:00, then I should select 08:00:00 on the next day (and of course, if the time is before 08:00:00, I should select 08:00:00 on that day).

How would that be implemented in the select clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN request_date < TRUNC( request_date ) + INTERVAL '8' HOUR
            THEN TRUNC( request_date ) + INTERVAL '8' HOUR
            WHEN request_date >= TRUNC( request_date ) + INTERVAL '19' HOUR
            THEN TRUNC( request_date ) + INTERVAL '32' HOUR
            ELSE request_date
            END AS adjusted_request_date
FROM   table_name
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXTRACT( HOUR FROM request_date ) < 8
            THEN TRUNC( request_date ) + INTERVAL '8' HOUR
            WHEN EXTRACT( HOUR FROM request_date ) >= 19
            THEN TRUNC( request_date ) + INTERVAL '32' HOUR
            ELSE request_date
            END AS adjusted_request_date
FROM   table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    case
      when to_char(request_date,'HH24') >= 19 
        then to_timestamp(to_char(trunc(request_date) +1,'YYYYMMDD') || '0800','YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
      when to_char(request_date,'HH24') < 8 
        then to_timestamp(to_char(trunc(request_date),'YYYYMMDD') || '0800','YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
      else request_date
    end as ReqStartTS
```